# Relationship between the Carmichael function and Euler's totient function

Tags: abstract-algebra, prime-numbers, computer-algebra-systems, carmichael-function

Let $\lambda$ denote the [Carmichael function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) and $\varphi$ [Euler's totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function). Furthermore, let $p$ denote any prime number and $k\in\mathbb{N}$. The wikipedia article about $\lambda$ states: $$\lambda(p^k)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{2}\varphi (p^k)&\text{, if }p=2\wedge k>2\\\varphi (p^k)&\text{, else}\end{cases}$$

I want to prove this statement. So, let $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $\gcd(a,p^k)=1$. From [Euler's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem), it follows: $$a^{\varphi (p^k)}\equiv 1\mod p^k$$ Thus, we've got $$\lambda (p^k)\le \varphi (p^k)$$How do I need to proceed from here?

Comment: Can $p = 2 \wedge k > 2$ please be explained? I do not understand the meaning of the mathematical statement.

Comment: @YajatShamji $\wedge$ denotes logical conjugation. So the statement means that $p=2$ *and* $k>2$.

Answer (score 4):

The key topic you want to look up is "primitive roots". Saying that $\lambda(p^k)=\phi(p^k)$ is equivalent to saying that $(\Bbb Z/p^k\Bbb Z)^\times$ is a cyclic group; this is what the known results on primitive roots assert. Any place that discusses primitive roots (for example, the book by Niven/Zuckerman/Montgomery) will also indicate how the situation is slightly different for powers of $2$, which will give you the special case as well.