# Proving that Carmichael function divides Euler's totient function with division

Tags: divisibility, totient-function, carmichael-function

I was looking at a proof for $\lambda(n) | \phi(n)$ using division.

Assume $\lambda(n)  \not| \phi(n).$   Then $\phi(n) = \lambda(n) * q + r$ and $ 1 \leq r \leq \lambda(n) -1.$

$1 = a^{\phi(n)} = a^{\lambda(n)*q+r} = (a^{\lambda(n)})^q * a^r = a^r\ (mod\ n),$

but then $a^r$ is less than $a^{\lambda(n)}$ which is a contradiction.

For starters, why is this true? $1 = a^{\phi(n)} (mod\ n).$  Is this by Euler's generalisation of Fermat's little theorem? the gcd(a,n) was never specified, so i didn't want to assume.

Second confusing part is $(a^{\lambda(n)})^q.$ I assume this disappears because $a^{\lambda(n)}\ (mod\ n) = 1.$  But why does this equal 1 then?

I guess it's a contradiction since $\lambda(n)$ should be the smallest number n such that $a^m \equiv 1\ (mod\ n).$

Comment: Please post the *entire* proof, including what it claims to be proving.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I think you should retract your close vote since the essence of the question is far from clear.

Comment: @BillDubuque Retracted. So see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/829472/relationship-between-the-carmichael-function-and-eulers-totient-function) for reference.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  If $\lambda(n) | \phi(n)$ then
$\phi(n) = \lambda(n) * q + r$ and $r=0.$  And Carmichael function $\lambda(n)$ is defined as least exponent for bases $a$ that are coprime to $n$

Comment: i restructured the proof hopefully it could be more clear now. @J.W.Tanner there are specific parts of the proof i don't understand. i've updated it so hopefully it became more clear

Comment: It's better now.  In the last line, I think you meant $m$ where you typed 'n'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your specific questions, firstly,

$a^{\phi(n)}\equiv1 \pmod n$ is indeed Euler's generalization of Fermat's little theorem.

The Carmichael function $\lambda(n)$ is defined as the least positive integer $m$

such that $a^m\equiv1\pmod n$ for all $a$ relatively prime to $n$, so that is why we assume gcd$(a,n)=1.$

Your second question was why $(a^{\lambda(n)})^q\times a^r\equiv a^r \pmod n.$

That is indeed because $a^{\lambda(n)}\ \equiv 1\pmod n,$

which follows from the definition of the Carmichael function $\lambda(n)$.

Thus $(a^{\lambda(n)})^q\times a^r\equiv 1^qa^r \equiv1a^r\equiv a^r\pmod n.$

Finally, yes, a contradiction occurs because we assumed that $a$ was any integer relatively prime to $n,$

and $\lambda$ is the least positive integer $m$ such that $a^m\equiv1 \pmod n$ for all such $a$,

and yet we just showed that $a^r\equiv1\pmod n$ for all such $a,$ and $r$ is positive and less than $\lambda$.

Comment: Great answer, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Let $\,E=E_n\,$ be the set of all exponents $\,e>0\,$ such that: $\ a^{\large e}\equiv 1\pmod{\!n}\,$ for all $a$ coprime to $n.\,$ By definition $\, \lambda(n)\,$ is the *least* element of $E.\,$ Note $E$ is *closed under positive subtraction,* $ $ i.e.

$$\color{#0A0}j>\color{#C00}k\,\in\,E\ \Rightarrow\ j\!-\!k\,\in E,\ \ \ {\rm by}\ \ \  1\equiv \color{#0A0}{a^{\large j}} \equiv a^{\large j-k}\, \color{#C00}{a^{\large k}} \equiv a^{\large j-k}\qquad \qquad $$

Theorem below $\,\Rightarrow\,\lambda(n)\,$ divides all elements in $E,\,$ including $\,\phi(n)\in E\,$ (by [Euler's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Euler's_theorem)).

**Remark** $ $ $\lambda(n)$ and its above property are *universal* generalizations of the notion of [order of an element](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/127118/242) in a group. Generally it is called the *(universal) exponent* of a group. It could also be called the *universal order*.  The proof in the OP is essentially Proof $2$ below - specialized to the case at hand.

---

**Theorem** $\ \ $ If a nonempty set of positive integers $\rm\,\cal O\,$ satisfies $\rm\ n > m\, \in\, {\cal O} \ \Rightarrow\  n\!-\!m\, \in\, \cal O$
then every element of $\rm\,\cal O\,$ is a multiple of the *least* element $\rm\:\ell \in\cal O.$

**Proof** $\ {\bf 1}\  $ If not there's a least nonmultiple $\rm\:n\in \cal O,\:$ contra  $\rm\:n\!-\!\ell \in \cal O\:$ is a nonmultiple of $\rm\:\ell. \, $

**Proof** ${\bf\ 2}\,\rm\ \ \cal O\,$ closed under subtraction $\rm\,\Rightarrow\,\cal O\,$ closed under remainder (mod), when it is nonzero, since mod is computable by repeated subtraction $\rm\, a\ mod\ b\, =\, a - k b\, =\, a-b-b-\cdots -b.\,$ Thus $\rm\,n\in \cal O\,$ $\Rightarrow$ $\rm\, (n\ mod\ \ell) = 0,\,$ else it is $\rm\,\in \cal O\,$ and smaller than $\rm\,\ell,\,$ contra mimimality of $\rm\,\ell.$

**Remark** $\ $ In a nutshell, two applications of induction yield the following inferences

$  \rm\begin{eqnarray} {\cal O}\rm\ closed\ under\ {\bf subtraction} &\Rightarrow\:&\rm {\cal O}\ closed\ under\ {\bf mod} = remainder = repeated\ subtraction \\
&\Rightarrow\:&\rm {\cal O}\ closed\ under\ {\bf gcd} = repeated\ mod\ (Euclid's\ algorithm) \end{eqnarray}$

Interpreted constructively, this yields the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/23500) for the gcd.

For more on the key innate structure  see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4715/242) on *order ideals* and *denominator ideals.*