# Finding a General Explicit Formula for $\lambda(n)$ for when $n\neq p^k$

Tags: totient-function, carmichael-function, derivation-of-formulae

I have been trying to answer the following question: Is there a general formula for Carmichael's totient function ($\lambda(n)$) that is analogous to the Euler product formula for Euler's totient function ($\varphi(n)$) (where $n \neq p^k$/when $n$ is composite)?

What I have done so far:

I know that $\varphi(n) = n (1 -\frac{1}{p_1})(1 -\frac{1}{p_2})\dots(1 -\frac{1}{p_k})$

(where $p_k$ denotes the $k$th prime that is a factor of $n$)

I also know that $\lambda(n)$ is equivalent to finding the smallest integer $m$ such that $a^m \equiv 1 (\text{mod}$ $n)$ holds for every integer $a$ that is coprime to $n$.

However, I can't proceed any further. Any tips or help would be much appreciated.

*Edit 1: Although I can now express $\lambda(n)$ in terms of $\varphi(n)$ for $n = p^k$ (which is given in [Relationship between the Carmichael function and Euler's totient function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/829472/relationship-between-the-carmichael-function-and-eulers-totient-function?rq=1)), I now want to know if there is a general formula for $\lambda(n)$ in terms of $\varphi(n)$ where $n \neq p^k$ (i.e when $n$ is composite).*

**Edit 2: I just recently found out about Euler's totient theorem (i.e.** $a^{\varphi(n)} \equiv 1 (\text{mod}$ $n)$ **) and recently learnt that** $\lambda(n)=\text{lcm}(\lambda(p_1^{r_1}), \lambda(p_2^{r_2}), \cdots, \lambda(p_m^{r_m}))$  **but still no breakthrough.**

Comment: Actually, you can use the formula for $\phi(n)$, which you know, because $\lambda (p^k)$ can be expressed by $\phi(p^k)$, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/829472/relationship-between-the-carmichael-function-and-eulers-totient-function?rq=1). Does this answer your question?

Comment: See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function)

Comment: Thanks, @DietrichBurde!

Comment: It does. Thanks! @DietrichBurde

Comment: What is the problem with the lcm-function ?

Comment: @Peter, there is no problem with the lcm-function. It is just I wanted a formula of $\lambda(n)$ that is analogous to the formula for $\varphi(n)$ when $n \neq p^k$.